# Dependency injection fails on a spring test when using @Qualifier

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm using JDK 1.7, intelliJ community 13, I'm writing a spring JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:test-applicationContext.xml"})
public class InstructionMessageTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("validator")
    public Validator validator;

    @Test
    public void shouldFailValidationWithLowInstructionType() throws Exception {
        InstructionMessage underTest = new InstructionMessage(0, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        underTest.getInstructionType();
////        validator.validate(underTest);
//        ApplicationContext tstctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test-applicationContrext.xml");
//        Validator validator = (Validator) tstctx.getBean("validator");
//        Set<ConstraintViolation<InstructionMessage>> errors = validator.validate(underTest);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFailValidationWithHighInstructiuontype() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

here is the application context

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.ian.*" />

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

</beans>
```

when i try to run the test

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.ian.beer.instructionProcessing.InstructionMessageTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public javax.validation.Validator org.ian.beer.instructionProcessing.InstructionMessageTest.validator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=validator)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:376)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public javax.validation.Validator org.ian.beer.instructionProcessing.InstructionMessageTest.validator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=validator)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=validator)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 31 more
```

When I uncomment manual lookup in the context, everything is working fine. Have I missed something?

Comment: This is a silly question, is it possible you have more than one test-applicationContext.xml file, as the xml file name listed in the commented code has a slightly different spelling

Answer (score 2):

You are doing 2 different things by annotation and in code. By annotation, you search for class matching interface and qualifier. In code, you match using unique bean name.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency.

This error is very clear: you have declared no bean of type `javax.validation.Validator` with qualifier "validator". You should do that like that:

```xml
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <qualifier value="validator"/>
</bean>
```

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Or as alternative, use exact mapping with `javax.annotation.Resource` annotation:

```
@javax.annotation.Resource(name="validator")
private Validator validator;
```

which is doing that what you were doing manually:

```
Validator validator = (Validator) tstctx.getBean("validator");
```

Comment: Łukasz L. many thanks for your comment, unfortunately your solution does not work also. I have already tried the @Resource annotation also, now you see why i have posted this question. So i added the <qualifier value="validator" to the bean definition and i still receive org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.ian.beer.instructionProcessing.InstructionMessageTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:

Comment: Sorry i am limited as to how many characters i can post here, it will not let me post the entire stack trace.....

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue. You are referring to test-applicationContext.xml in your classpath.

"When I uncomment manual lookup in the context, everything is working fine"

That's because the file is called test-applicationContrext.xml......i.e. you have spelt it differently. Please check your work throughly before posting on this forum